# Submit form and save values to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, forms, html, session-storage

How can I save values from form to sessionStorage when the form is submitted?

Something like this?

```
        <form id="myForm" method="get" action="lista.html" rel="external" data-ajax="false" >

        <label for="autonumero"> Anna autonumero </label>
        <input type='tel' name="autonumero" data-corners="false"/>


        <input type="submit" onclick="saveData()" value="OK" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" />



        <script> function savedata()
{ var input = document.getElementById("autonumero");
sessionStorage.setItem("autonumero", input.value); 
</script> 






        </form>
```

The form needs to be submitted also so just saving the values isn't enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return saveData();" value="OK" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function savedata() { 
  var input = document.getElementById("autonumero");
  sessionStorage.setItem("autonumero", input.value);
  return true;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: when I alert(sessionStorage.getItem("autonumero")); it just returns null

Answer (score 1):

try set input id id="autonumero"

```
<input id="autonumero" type="submit" onclick="return saveData();" value="OK" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `id="autonumero"` to the input field:

```
<input type='tel' id="autonumero" name="autonumero" data-corners="false"/>
```